# Get profileDisplayedUserKey on Homepage of IBM Connections

Tags: ibm-connections

I am developing some widgets for IBM Conections. One of the requirements is a widget on the homepage which will get the user based content.
On a Profile page there you can get ProfileUserkey by calling

```
this.iContext.getiWidgetAttributes().getItemValue(“profileDisplayedUserKey”);
```

I want to know if this also applicable for the homepage? Can I get the Profileuserkey by the same method or is there another/better way?

Comment: if you cant you can always get the macro {profiles} which would let you query the profiles service /profiles/atom/service.do http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/dx/07072009105437%D8%B5WEBKH7.htm and get the current user's key

Comment: Paul, I already figured it out. iContext has something like getUserProfile() and from this ItemSet you can get directly the email of the current user.

Comment: add it as an answer, and mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

Paul, I already figured it out. iContext has something like getUserProfile() and from this ItemSet you can get directly the email of the current user.